# How to generate a number with "Random.range" to change scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, random, numbers

I have this script:

```
public class EmpezarJuego : MonoBehaviour {

int number;

public void Empezar() {

    number = Random.Range(1,4);

    if (number == 1) {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("GAME");
    }
    if (number == 2) {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("GAME_1");
    }
    if (number == 3) {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("GAME_2");
    }
    if (number == 4) {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("GAME_3");
    }



 }
}
```

I want: If number = 1, my scene is GAME, if number = 2, then, my scene is GAME_1 .... BUT **it NOT WORKS** why??

Comment: In what way is it not working? Does your code at least enter the appropriate if statement? Also, the upper bound for `Random.Range()` with int values is exclusive - meaning if you want to number to be from 1-4, you should actually have `Random.Range(1,5)`.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Have you added the scenes to the build index?

Comment: LOL @Fredrik +1 ! I forgot to add scenes to the build index! thanks!

Comment: You can simplify that `8` lines code of `if/else` statements code to `1` with `SceneManager.LoadScene("GAME_" + (number - 1).ToString())`. Now change the first *GAME* scene to *GAME_0*.

Comment: @Fredrik You should probably post an answer so he can close this question. If everything works now.

Comment: Good idea, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SceneManager to work you need to add the scene to the build index. You do this in:

> File -> Build Settings -> Add Open Scenes

After that you can call `SceneManager.LoadScene("NameOfScene")` or if you, for instance, want to load the next level you can write

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
```

to load the next scene in the build index list.

Comment: It would be good to add that his Random.Range(1,4) will never have the value 4.

Comment: Indeed! Unless you're using floats, where the max value is inclusive. `int Random.Range` has exclusive max.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html), `Random.Range`...

> Returns a random int number between and min [inclusive] and max [exclusive]

This means that you will have to do `Random.Range(1,5)` to have the fourth `if` hit.

Hope that solves it!

*P. S. You should use a `switch(number)` instead of `if` blocks.*

Comment: I know that's how it works but according to the docs it says both min and max is inclusive... But max is clearly not inclusive if you need to +1 it to get it included. It says **Note that max is inclusive, so using Random.Range( 0.0f, 1.0f ) could return 1.0 as a value.** in the docs, which suggests otherwise. But clearly this is not the case, I just tested it myself. Weird

Comment: Nevermind. That's the float overload. The int overload has an EXCLUSIVE max. That makes sense, haha.